# How does spring security maintain authentication information between request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session, jsessionid

How does spring security maintain authentication info between requests?

Does it use any thing similar to jSessionId or uses an entirely different mechanism.

Further, I see that the [AbstractSecurityInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.html) (I mean, any of it's implementations) is responsible for intercepting the incoming request and verify if a request is already authorized using `Authentication.isAuthenticated()` and then depending on the condition either validate the request or send the Authentication request to an AuthenticationManager Implementation. So, in other words, how does AbstractSecurityInterceptor differentiate between first request and subsequent request.

Comment: this is related to jsessionid cookies , every request the browser send the last as header parm , then server intercept it and check wether it's authenticated , authorized , or anonymous session ( not that this param is the ID of created session object in the server)

Comment: how does the spring keep a mapping between jsessionid and the userdetails, which classes handle this mapping functionality. This is precisely what I am looking for so i can explore more about these classes.

Comment: when u login, in the created session there will be stored the security context object in the `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` session key , so all security info ( including userDetails will be stored there) .

Comment: You can also work without a session and without a session cookie, e.g. if you use JWTs. It's a token issued by an identiy provider. The client adds the JWT to the HTTP header of each request.

Comment: well, jwt is gr8... it's payload bundles the entire user's roles/permissions 'to and fro'... so Security Context would not have to bother about storing roles internally... but the use case I am trying to understand is the basic authentication... with out JWT or OAuth (at least for the moment.)

Comment: But any info on JWT, OAuth is welcomed either.

Answer (score 6):

Spring Security uses a [`SecurityContextRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.html) to store and retrieve the `SecurityContext` for the current security session.

The default implementation is the [`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html) which utilizes the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` to store/retrieve the `SecurityContext`.

The underlying servlet container will obtain the correct `HttpSession` for the incoming request, generally due to a session identifier being passed in a cookie or request parameter. For Spring Security it doesn't matter as that is thus loaded of to the underlying servlet container.

Comment: gr8. Can you clarify on "it doesn't matter as that is thus loaded of to the underlying servlet container." Do you mean spring security does not use session identifier like jsessionid.

Comment: It doesn’t. It uses the servlet-api and lets the servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow) deal with the specifics. So Spring Security only deals with the `HttpSession` how that is created doesn’t matter for Spring Security as it only uses an API.

Comment: Otherway said, the `jsessionid` we see on the browser is coming from ApplicationServer. And just like in the servlet world, the spring security also handles with details (jsessionid) retrived from the httpsession object. And here instead of the application code handling the httpsession, spring handles it transparently. And the application code no more requires to bother about httpsession and can work at a higher abstraction i.e `SecurityContext`

Comment: HttpSession is part of the servlet API. Spring security, for the web, uses the servlet API. It is just Java build on top of existing API’s

Comment: I think we are on same page. Correct me if I quoted any thing wrong on the previous comment. :-) gr8. It's better to be clear and double check - it's security at the end-of-day.

Comment: but i see one limitation with this abstraction of HttpSession. I could add additional information, not just auth info in to HttpSession obj simply in an agile fashion. But with Spring security, it looks like i have do bit of more work.. like custom user obj and any thing else... which would be not so agile.

Comment: Why would the fact that you use Spring Security suddenly change you not being able to access and use the `HttpSession` anymore? Also if you have a custom user object you would need to hook that into Spring Security (if that is the user object you want to use as `UserDetails` that is).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197673/discussion-between-samshers-and-m-deinum).

Comment: would you mind helping me with this related stuff: (Which class stores the JSESSIONID value in spring security?)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048440/which-class-stores-the-jsessionid-value-in-spring-security]

Comment: in the context of these two Q, the `remember-me` cookie should also be a servlet container thing, which is inturn used by the spring-security. Is that right?

Comment: cookies, as sessions, are a part of the servlet-api.